# 2 client contexts using the same success method

Tags: list, javascript, custom-list, user-profile-property

Is there anyway to have 2 client contexts in the same success method like so

```
             var clientContext = SP.ClientContext.get_current();

        var peopleManager = new SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager(clientContext);

    // Get user properties for the target user.
    // To get the PersonProperties object for the current user, use the
    // getMyProperties method.
    MyProperties = peopleManager.getMyProperties();

    var editLinksList = clientContext.get_site().get_rootWeb().get_lists().getByTitle('EditableProperties'),
    editcamlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();

editcamlQuery.set_viewXml('');
var editcollListItems = editLinksList.getItems(editcamlQuery);



clientContext.load(editcollListItems);

    // Load the PersonProperties object and send the request.
    clientContext.load(MyProperties);
    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(getMyNewsChoicesSuccess, getMyNewsChoicesFail);
```

Basically I want to use what I get from one of my share point lists and use it to search in my profile properties. 
Any other methods of how to do this would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need a new context to do this, you just need seperate list and item collections.

If you have to get list 1, then use it to get stuff from list2:

```
var ctx = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var web = ctx.get_web();

var firstList = web.get_lists().getByTitle("List1");
var firstListItems = firstList.getItems(new SP.CamlQuery.createAllItemsQuery());
ctx.load(firstListItems);

ctx.executeQueryAsync(function() {
    //do some processing with list1 to figure out what you need to get from list2
    //then
    var secondList = web.get_lists().getByTitle("List2");
    var secondListItems = secondList.getItems(new SP.CamlQuery.createAllItemsQuery());
    ctx.load(secondListItems);
    ctx.executeQueryAsync(function() {
        //do something with the secondListItems
    }, function(sender, args) { alert('failed to get secondListItems'); })

}, function(sender, args) { alert('failed to get firstListItems'); });
```

If you just need items from both lists:

```
var ctx = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var web = ctx.get_web();

var firstList = web.get_lists().getByTitle("List1");
var firstListItems = firstList.getItems(new SP.CamlQuery.createAllItemsQuery());
ctx.load(firstListItems);
var secondList = web.get_lists().getByTitle("List2");
var secondListItems = secondList.getItems(new SP.CamlQuery.createAllItemsQuery());
ctx.load(secondListItems);

ctx.executeQueryAsync(function() {
    //do something with all the list items you've loaded so far
}, function(sender, args) {
    alert('failed to get loaded items');
});
```

I've used anonymous success and failure functions, but you can definitely name the success and failure functions and re-use them.

This is one of the fundamental advantages of the JSOM over the REST API, you can retrieve many seperate resources from the server with a single network call (using executeQueryAsync), because you tell the context what items to go retrieve (using `load()`) or modify on the server (using `update()`)